# How do I create a function with a parameter that works inside addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm quite new to this. I would like to create a function in JavaScript that will allow me to change the linear gradient background property for the body in CSS by switching radio buttons and using addEventListener.

I have come up with something like this:

(color1 and color2 are color inputs in html, radio1 is one of four radio buttons)

```
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");

function gradientPosition(x) {
    return body.style.background =
    "linear-gradient(to " + x +","
    + color1.value 
    + ", "
    + color2.value
    + ")";
}
```

This works when I type it in the console and add one of the parameters ie. 
`gradientPosition("top");`. My problem is that it doesn't work when I use it with addEventListener:

```
radio1.addEventListener("click", gradientPosition("top"));
```

I guess this is because te click itself is calling the function and the argument "top" won't work? What is the solution for this kind of problem? Or should I just stick with anonymous functions inside the listener in this case?

Thank you for your time and understanding!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function rather than passing a valid handler.  Your approach is actually passing as handler the following string:

```
"linear-gradient(to " + x +"," + color1.value + ", " + color2.value + ")";
```

*You should follow this approach:*

```
radio1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    gradientPosition("top");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works and it also helps me understand what I did wrong:)